# ExpandableListView Crash after Android 14 update

Tags: java, android, crash, expandablelistview, android-14

Component: `android.widget.ExpandableListView`
Method: `onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfoForItem`
Error: `NullPointerException in getUnflattenedPos on ExpandableListConnector (null object reference)`
Stack Trace: Provided in the request (see below)
Affected Devices: Some devices running Android 14 and later

Stack Trace

```
`android.widget.ExpandableListView.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfoForItem (ExpandableListView.java:1154)
android.widget.AbsListView$ListItemAccessibilityDelegate.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo (AbsListView.java:2800)
android.view.View.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo (View.java:9299)
android.view.View.createAccessibilityNodeInfoInternal (View.java:9260)
android.view.View$AccessibilityDelegate.createAccessibilityNodeInfo (View.java:33380)
android.view.View.createAccessibilityNodeInfo (View.java:9243)
android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$AccessibilityNodePrefetcher.prefetchDescendantsOfRealNode (AccessibilityInteractionController.java:1592)
android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$AccessibilityNodePrefetcher.prefetchDescendantsOfRealNode (AccessibilityInteractionController.java:1615)
android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$AccessibilityNodePrefetcher.prefetchAccessibilityNodeInfos (AccessibilityInteractionController.java:1381)
android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController.findAccessibilityNodeInfoByAccessibilityIdUiThread (AccessibilityInteractionController.java:425)
android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController.-$$Nest$mfindAccessibilityNodeInfoByAccessibilityIdUiThread
android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$PrivateHandler.handleMessage (AccessibilityInteractionController.java:1785)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:230)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:319)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8893)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:608)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1103)`
```

The error does not occur on all devices running Android 14 or later, suggesting potential device-specific variations or configurations.
We have reviewed known issues and documentation but haven't found a direct match for this behavior.
We suspect the error might be related to changes in ExpandableListView or related classes in Android 14.